# State of MOSFET after getting fried?

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I'm working on a project were I need to cut the power going to the ignition coil on a motorbike (produces pretty high voltages) for small amounts of time using an arduino. The switching needs to happen very fast.

I was planning to go for a MOSFET (P-Channel) since, even if the Arduino malfunctions for some reason the coil will still get power. But, again, for some reason if the MOSFET gets damaged will the connection remain closed or will it be open ?
Also, will a MOSFET be the best option here ?

EDIT:
Switching would need to happen under 100ms.

Comment: Could you specify "fast" switching time? Are you trying to make an automatic gearbox? :)

Comment: The power going *to* the ignition coil? That is not at high voltages, thats at the battery voltage indeed. And I'm not quite sure a mosfet with undriven gate can act in a predictable way. As said, specify "very fast", maybe a relais is just enough (and it's better), maybe a solid state relais.

Comment: Your entire second paragraph doesn't make sense. How is the coil still getting powered if the Arduino malfunctions?

Comment: I'm trying to make a quickshifter :) So switching time would need to be less than _atleast_ 100ms.

Comment: "less than at least 100 ms" - makes no sense in context, the value could be less than 100 ms or less than 900 ms etc but would never be less than 100 ms.

Comment: The switching time depends on how fast the MOSFET is saturated. I'm using MOSFET in circuits with shorter switching times. Please draw a circuit and add that to your question!

Comment: Actually 100ms is really slow for silicon device :)

Answer (score 1):

Resistance of damaged transistor is unpredictable.

If you want to cut-off ingition - you should shutdown gate signal for transistor or thyristor that is already driving ignition coil instead of cutting off high current.

Answer (score 0):

Generally failure will result in a short. You can protect the coil with some kind of current limit like a polyfuse.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that the shorted MOSFET may subsequently burn out, and possibly explode, resulting in an open condition.  This depends on the circuit, and is a fire hazard that needs to be protected against, like with a polyfuse.